# SQL Query to fetch information based on one or more condition. Getting combinations instead of exact number

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I have two tables. Table 1 has about 750,000 rows and table 2 has 4 million rows. Table two has an extra ID field in which I am interested, so I want to write a query that will check if the 750,000 table 1 records exist in table 2. For all those rows in table 1 that exist in table 2, I want the respective ID based on same SSN. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT distinct b.UID, a.* 
  FROM [Analysis].[dbo].[Table1] A, [Proteus_8_2].dbo.Table2 B
  where a.ssn = b.ssn
```

Instead of getting 750,000 rows in the output, I am getting 5.4 million records. Where am i going wrong? 
Please help?

Comment: can an SSN show up more than once in Table2? If so, would the UID be the same for both SSN's?

Comment: Is ssn a primary in table1? In table2, can an ssn have two uids?

Comment: SSN is not primary and yes, SSN can show up any number of times in Table 2. And yes, UID will be same for same SSN.

Comment: First stop using implicit joins. They were replaced more than 20 years ago with explicit joins that are far better. Implicit joins are an SQL Server antipattern and it is inexcusable to still be using them.

Comment: @HLGEM- I am a rookie in SQL and have no idea what you're saying. Could you please try and explain with a sample query?

Comment: @UtsavChatterjee - have you had any success with your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requesting all the rows in your select if b.UID is a unique field in column two.

Also if SSN is not unique in table one you can get the higher row count than the total row count for table 2.

You need to consider what you want from table 2 again.

EDIT

You can try this to return distinct combinations of ssn and uid when ssn is found in table 2 provided that ssn and uid have a cardinality of 1:1, i.e., every unique ssn has a single unique uid.

```
select distinct
    a.ssn,b.[UID]
from [Analysis].[dbo].[Table1] a
cross apply
    ( select top 1 [uid] from [Proteus_8_2].[dbo].[Table2] where ssn = a.ssn ) b
where b.[UID] is not null
```

Comment: I just want to look up at table 2 to see if the any of the 750,000 records in Table 1 exist there. Whichever are found, must be given the same UID. UID's are present only in Table 2

Comment: Could you confirm a scenario, when an SSN exists in table 2 in 5 different rows, e.g. SSN875, would the UID in table 2 always be the same for each of those five rows or would it change?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT distinct b.UID, a.* 
  FROM [Analysis].[dbo].[Table1] A LEFT JOIN [Proteus_8_2].dbo.Table2 B
  on a.ssn = b.ssn
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the order detail table is in a one-many relationship to the order table, that is the expected result of any join. If you want something different, you need to define for us the business rule that will tell us how to select only one record from the Order detail table. You cannot effectively write SQL code without understanding the business rules that of what you are trying to achieve. You should never just willy nilly select one record out of the many, you need to understand which one you want.